# Is it possible to make a variable which can take the value of different values defined in a structure in C?

Tags: c, variables, optimization, struct

Suppose if define a structure as and define an array:

```c
typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

Is it possible to make a variable which can take the value of rgbtBlue / rbgtGreen / rgbtRed?

Like:

```c
int main()
{
    RGBTRIPLE image[2];
    VARIABLE = ??;
    RGBTRIPLE image_1[0].VARIABLE = func(image[0].VARIABLE);
}

RGBTRIPLE func(RGBTRIPLE image[0].VARIABLE)
{
    image[0].VARIABLE = 255;
    return image[0].VARIABLE;
}
```

I want to make a function which can take input of image[0].rgbtRed, image[0].rgbtGreen and image[0].rgbtBlue then modify the values individually. Here, the aim would be to change all the values to 255 to make a white pixel with the help of VARIABLE which I don't know how to define. Basically, I want the variable to refer to the struct defined already and first take the value of rgbtRed, then rgbtGreen and finally, rgbtBlue.

Comment: It's not exactly  clear what you're doing. Please amend the question to show the 3 separate functions you know how to do and ask if there's a better way.

Comment: Unless the function needs to know the values of the other two components at the same time, you could have `image[0].rgbtRed = myFunc(image[0].rgbtRed);` and process each component in turn.

Comment: Instead of individual struct members, use a single member that's an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically asking how to replicate C++'s pointers to members in C. You can build this around the `offsetof` macro, like this:

```
#include <stddef.h>

const size_t RED = offsetof(RGBTRIPLE, rgbtRed);
const size_t GREEN = offsetof(RGBTRIPLE, rgbtGreen);
const size_t BLUE = offsetof(RGBTRIPLE, rgbtBlue);

#define VARIABLECOLOR(x, color) (*(BYTE *)((char *)&(x) + (color)))
```

And use it like this:

```
RGBTRIPLE image[2];
size_t color = RED;
VARIABLECOLOR(image[0], color) = 255;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of individual struct members, use a single member that's an array, as in:

```
enum { RED, GREEN, BLUE };

typedef struct {
    BYTE component[3];
} RGBTRIPLE;

// ...

channel = GREEN;
foo.component[channel] = 255;
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without changing the struct? I have applied some other filters already using the same struct.

Comment: You can use a complex dance of `offsetof` and pointer arithmetic, but if you get it subtly wrong you have UB. See Joseph's answer.